# Can't connect to MySQL database with Paramiko, can with sshtunnel

Tags: mysql-python, paramiko, mysql-connector, pythonanywhere, ssh-tunnel

My code was using `sshtunnel` and connected to my database correctly. However due to a conflict between `grequests` and `sshtunnel` I had to switch to using another library for the `ssh`, and have had most luck with `Paramiko` (as that works with `monkeypatch` on `grequests`).

The `ssh tunnel` section is working correctly, however I am now getting the message:

`An error occurred: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'PA_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I'm using environment variables that haven't changed, as far as I can see everything is the same between the working code with `sshtunnel` and without `grequests`, and the version with `Paramiko` that can't connect.

Full code here:

```
from gevent import monkey

monkey.patch_all()

import grequests
import mysql.connector
import paramiko
from pprint import pprint
import os

ssh_password = os.environ.get("PA_SSH_PASS")
db_password = os.environ.get("PA_DB_PASS")
database = os.environ.get("PA_DB_NAME")

def get_current_listing_urls():
    try:
        ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)

        ssh_client.connect(
            "ssh.eu.pythonanywhere.com",
            username=PA_username,
            password=ssh_password,
        )

        transport = ssh_client.get_transport()

        channel = transport.open_channel(
            "direct-tcpip",
            dest_addr=("PA_username.mysql.eu.pythonanywhere-services.com", 3306),
            src_addr=("127.0.0.1", 3306),
        )

        db = mysql.connector.connect(
            user="PA_username",
            password=db_password,
            host="127.0.0.1",
            port=3306,
            database=database,
            use_pure=True,
        )

        table_name = "listings"

        cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)

        query = f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {table_name};"

        cursor.execute(query)

        results = cursor.fetchall()

        return results

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
    finally:
        if "cursor" in locals() and cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if "db" in locals() and db:
            db.close()
        if "ssh_client" in locals() and ssh_client:
            ssh_client.close()


old_listing_urls = get_current_listing_urls()

pprint(old_listing_urls)
```

I've tried just about everything I can think of, but I can't see where I'm going wrong. The message presumably means it's connecting and trying to authenticate, but failing. However the database name, username, and password are all correct as they are all working when using sshtunnel.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

EDIT:

The working code with `sshtunnel` is here:

```
import mysql.connector
import sshtunnel
from pprint import pprint
import time
import os
import json

sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

ssh_password = os.environ.get("PA_SSH_PASS")
db_password = os.environ.get("PA_DB_PASS")
database = os.environ.get("PA_DB_NAME")


def get_current_listing_urls():
    try:
        with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
            ("ssh.eu.pythonanywhere.com"),
            ssh_username=PA_username,
            ssh_password=ssh_password,
            remote_bind_address=(
                "PA_username.mysql.eu.pythonanywhere-services.com",
                3306,
            ),
            threaded=False,
        ) as tunnel:
            db = mysql.connector.connect(
                user=PA_username,
                password=db_password,
                host="127.0.0.1",
                port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
                database=database,
                use_pure=True,
            )

            table_name = "listings"

            cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)

            query = f"SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM {table_name};"  

            cursor.execute(query)

            results = cursor.fetchall()

            return results

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
    finally:
        if "cursor" in locals() and cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if "db" in locals() and db:
            db.close()
        if "tunnel" in locals() and tunnel:
            tunnel.close()


old_listing_urls = get_current_listing_urls()

pprint(old_listing_urls)
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? Isn't something (local database?) listening already on the local port 3306? Did you try different port? If you forward the port manually (e.g. using `ssh`), can you connect through it with `mysql.connector.connect`? Post also your (previously) working sshtunnel code. Btw, sshtunnel is just a small layer on top of Paramiko. So I do not see what problem you might have with using it.

Comment: Hi Martin, apologies for vanishing like that. I tried manually forwarding with `ssh -L 3333:PA_username.mysql.eu.pythonanywhere-services.com:3306 PA_username@ssh.eu.pythonanywhere.com` in cmd and the database connection then works correctly (starting the code with mysql.connector section).

I think you're correct re local port, I found a local database and closed it. That changed the error message from the one above to `Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (10061 [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)`.

Comment: Changing all port numbers to eg `3333` makes the code hang indefinitely with no errors.  Having the destination as `3306`, and the ports on mysql.connector and in the tunnel source both as `3333` gives `Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3333' (10061 [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)` again. 

I'm sure I'm doing something silly, I'm just too far out of my depth to know exactly what to ask to what to try next.

The working code using sshtunnel is added above.

Comment: No dice unfortunately, `2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:12000' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

Comment: Change the port only in `port=3306,` and `src_addr=("127.0.0.1", 3306),` + Though actually, I think that Paramiko does not listen on the port at all. You have to implement that yourself and forward the data from the port to the channel. That's what sshtunnel does. I still do not understand why you cannot use it. Or at least copy over its code.

Comment: I'm not sure either what the problem is honestly, they are so similar. However the monkey,patch doesn't work when I use sshtunnel, and does work when I use Paramiko. When I use sshtunnel I get `Could not connect to gateway ssh.eu.pythonanywhere.com:22 : Error reading SSH protocol banner cannot switch to a different thread
An error occurred: Could not establish session to SSH gateway`. When I use Paramiko I can run commands, eg `ls` will return the files in the directory on the server, but I can't get the database connection to work.

Comment: Adding this after the line 
`ssh_client.connect()` will print the directory on the server: 

`stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("ls")

output = stdout.read().decode("utf-8")
print(output)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve this how I wanted to, in the end I used subprocess to run an ssh command in cmd and close it afterwards. This needed an rsa key instead of a password as I couldn't enter the password into cmd after sending the ssh command. Normally pevent would be used for this, but the function needed (spawn) doesn't work on windows. Using a key means no password entry is required.

Full code:

```
import subprocess
from db_utilities import get_current_listing_urls

# Define the SSH command to establish a tunnel
ssh_command = "ssh -L 3333:PA_username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com:3306 PA_username@ssh.pythonanywhere.com"

# Open a new cmd window and run the SSH command
cmd_process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["cmd", "/K", ssh_command],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True,
    text=True,
)

try:
    results = get_current_listing_urls()
    print(results)
finally:
    # Check if the process is still running, and terminate it if necessary
    if cmd_process.poll() is None:
        print("Closing SSH Tunnel")
        cmd_process.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have multiple matches for the host and username in your mysql.user table?  See the documentation here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-access.html

under "When multiple matches are possible"

Basically, if you have more than one match, then mysql decides which one to use.  It could be that one works locally but not remotely.  Can you post the user table (without the passwords) so we can see if there are conflicts and help you resolve them.

Comment: Not in this case - PythonAnywhere doesn't give you access to the user table, there is just one default user that you can use.